# How to add params with blank in argparse

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I try to show movie information in terminal.But got some problem is that I can't type 'rottentomatoes top gun' How can I edit the code to get multiple params in terminal.

Here's my github repo: https://github.com/Ray0907/movie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote the movie name in shell so that it will be passed to script as one argument:

```
rottentomatoes 'top gun'
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help